# PSStackedViewController cannot push view in Landscape mode on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, git, ipad

Hey I am using PSStackedViewController for my iPad app. we had the iPhone app (which is portrait only) and now I am converting it to iPad. So I converted the project to Universal settings and added support for both Landscape and portrait. I am having troubles pushing my view Controller on the stack, the code works fine for portrait and even if I change orientation after pushing controllers in portrait they appear fine in Landscape but I can't push from Landscape.My sample push code is below. DKNavigationController is a custom Navigation

```
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
CustomNavigationController *nav = [[CustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[nav setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController]];
nav.view.width = 320;
[delegate.stackController pushViewController:nav fromViewController:nil animated:animated];
```

and git link for the PSStackedViewController is here.
https://github.com/steipete/PSStackedView

I'll be thankful for your help. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Console log please
Is your delegate.stackController is UINavigationController?

Comment: Its a PSStackedViewController, The problem is the pushed view doesn't appear on the screen even though viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear are being called but view isn't rendered on screen.

Comment: After that your application works? (button action or touch)

Comment: Yea it still works fine if I come back to portrait, it is responsive in the Landscape also (Buttons,touch) but only the push functionality doesn't seem to work. It might be related to initWithNibName method as I am creating the views from interface builder but I noticed the ViewController is being created correctly just not rendering on screen. :(

Comment: tried with animation NO?

Comment: yea but it didn't work either

Comment: tried 'dispatch_time_t'? Try to excute after a delay.